# Method within a method in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

**Language:** python-3.7.3
**Framework:** Robot Framework-3.1.1
**IDE:** Pycharm
**Proficiency:** Novice

I have an user defined method written in python which returns string after replacing matching characters(s).

**String:** (12356, )

**Character to replace:** ( and , and )

**replacecharacter:** ${empty}

**Expected:** 123456

**Method:**

```
def replace_a_specific_character_in_a_String(self, str_var, replacingCharacter, charactertoReplace):
    str = str_var.replace(replacingCharacter, charactertoReplace)
    return str
```

**I wish to call the same method from my robot file as below.**

```
${response}=    replace a specific character in a String    [replace a specific character in a String    ${response}    , ${EMPTY})   ${EMPTY}]     (        ${EMPTY}
```

**This throws the below error**

```
Keyword 'Methods.Replace A Specific Character In A String' expected 3 arguments, got 6.
```

I understood the error message as it takes method inside the method as parameters. So what is the correct syntax to be followed in such cases. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, your function expects 3 arguments:

- str_var
- replacingCharacter
- charactertoReplace

However, you're passing it six. Consider this line of code:

```
replace a specific character in a String    [replace a specific character in a String    ${response}    , ${EMPTY})   ${EMPTY}]     (        ${EMPTY}
```

Because robot uses two or more spaces as an argument separator, these are the arguments it is passing to your function:

- [replace a specific character in a String
- ${response}
- , ${EMPTY})
- ${EMPTY}]
- (
- ${EMPTY}

If I understand what you're trying to do, you're wanting to call the keyword once, and then pass the result of that function to the keyword again. Robot doesn't let you do that. You'll have to run the keyword twice, saving the result of the first call and passing it to the second.

For example:

```
${tmp}=  replace a specific character in a String    ${response}  (  ${EMPTY}
${response}=  replace a specific character in a String  ${tmp}  )  ${EMPTY}
```